# ignore or close zabbix problem for a period of time

Tags: triggers, intervals, zabbix

I have both zabbix 3 and zabbix 5. I have a template that monitors Database statistics. there is a trigger that is important, but sometimes when we are operating on Database the trigger is not needed because we caused that situation. sometimes i don't want this trigger on my dashboard so i attend to close it. but the interval for its item is 60s and after a minute it appears again. so is there any way to close or ignore a trigger for a period of time?

i don't want to put the machine in maintenance mode because operation may take a week. i can't disable the item, we need its data and history. i can't change it's interval since it is in template.

in this question [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58783241/mark-a-hostname-problem-as-resolved-in-zabbix) someone explained about closing the problem but it's not what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Zabbix 4, you can put a single item in maintenance using Tags.

> If maintenance tags are specified, maintenance for the selected hosts will still be activated, but problems will only be suppressed (i.e. no actions will be taken) if their tags are a match.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/maintenance

So:

- tag the trigger in the template
- create a maintenace for that host/tag and activate it when needed

Comment: so i can use 'close' and 'maintenance' together to achieve my goal.